# How to use pre_get_posts to alter posts_per_page of category pages, where 'posts_per_page' will be dynamic

Tags: custom-field, pagination, pre-get-posts

I have Category templates with custom fields in Edit Category page of WordPress. One custom field there is to put How many posts per page to show in the category page. I am using `pre_get_posts` to change the default `posts_per_page` for the category pages.

Here is my function:

```
function my_limit_posts_per_cat_page( $query ){
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
$cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");
$category_posts_pp = '';
if(isset($cat_data['category_posts_pp'])){
$category_posts_pp = $cat_data['category_posts_pp']; //this is the custom field value available in edit category page
}
if(isset($cat_data['category_posts_pp'])){
$post_show_limit = $category_posts_pp;
} else {
$post_show_limit = get_option('posts_per_page'); //if the custom field is empty the Reading Settings posts per page will be using
}

if ( is_category() ){
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $post_show_limit );
    return;
}
```

And the `pre_get_posts` hook I used for that function:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_limit_posts_per_cat_page' );
```

The problem is, the custom field value is not being passed here. Whatever I put in the custom field in edit category page, the value is not working in my function. But, the same custom field value is working in other places (ie; template pages).

However, sometimes I see the the custom field value is working there, but in that case the pagination creates issues. For example: There are 19 posts in the category page and 10 is set from Reading Settings. So, by default there will be 2 pages. Now, if in the custom field I put 4, then there will be 5 pages. It shows 5 pages in the pagination correctly. But, the pages works till 2nd page. The 3rd page, 4th page and 5th page does not work. If we set 7 instead of 10 in Reading Settings, then the paginated pages works till 3rd page, and then the rest pages goes blank or 404.

Anybody there to show me what went wrong there? If you need more explanations please ask.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have pretty permalinks enabled? `cat` is only set if permalinks are set to default, otherwise `category_name` contains the category slug.

Comment: Yes, I have pretty permalinks enabled. The problem is, the custom field value is not being passed in my function {function my_limit_posts_per_cat_page( $query )}. Whatever I put in the custom field in edit category page, the value is not working in my function. But, the same custom field value is working in other places (ie; template pages).

Comment: `cat` is empty then, so the problem is in the very first line of your code. You need to get the category ID from the slug contained in `category_name`. Right now `$cat_data` is empty in every case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a correct suggestion. The `$cat_data` is never empty there. I have used this `$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');` to retrieve Category ID. the function  `get_query_var('cat');` always fetch the current category. See this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) here.

Comment: That works *after* the query is run, but in a `pre_get_posts` action, that var is not populated yet when pretty permalinks are enabled and you are visiting a category archive. I copied/pasted your code in a clean install of WordPress and have confirmed this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pretty permalinks enabled and you visit a category archive, the query var that gets populated is `category_name`. The `cat` query var will only be populated *after* the query is run. So while your code will work in a template, it won't work in a `pre_get_posts` action for this reason.

To fix this, you need to get the category ID from the category slug:

```
function my_limit_posts_per_cat_page( $query ){
    if( $query->is_main_query() && is_category() ){

        $cat_slug = get_query_var( 'category_name' );
        $category = get_term_by( 'slug', $cat_slug, 'category' );
        $cat_id = $category->term_id;

        // the rest of your code using $cat_id goes here...
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_limit_posts_per_cat_page' );
```

Note one other addition here is the use of `$query->is_main_query()` to limit this code to run only on the main query.

My general suggestion when developing is to log *everything* and verify that the data you are working with is what you expect. Timing is everything in WordPress.

Comment: Tried your solution, did not work :(
This line `$cat_id = $category->term_id;` produce the following error:
**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object** . Thanks for your effort though.